# bash - execute cmd2 each time cmd1 stdout yields specific string

Tags: linux, bash, script

I'm trying to run

```
WID=`xdotool search "Inbox" | head -1`
xdotool windowactivate $WID
xdotool key Up
```

each time stdout of

```
$ CAMEL_DEBUG=all evolution
```

yields "starting idle".

I've come up with this script, which does what I want, but only once, it isn't doing it every time "starting idle" is shown, but only once and stops. I don't know bash good enough to force it to repeat itself endlessly.

```
exec 3< <(CAMEL_DEBUG=all evolution)

while read line; do
   case "$line" in
   *"starting idle"*)
      echo "'$line' contains staring idle"

    WID=`xdotool search "Inbox" | head -1`
        xdotool windowactivate $WID
        xdotool key Up

      break
      ;;
   *)
      echo "'$line' does not contain starting idle."
      ;;
   esac
done <&3

exec 3<&-
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` command terminates the `while` loop. Drop it.

Comment: I know, this is just an example of what works but only once. Dropping the break command isn't good enough, of course I tried it. Some deeper change in the script is needed to be repeated infinitely, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: If dropping `break` is not sufficient, then it's probably a buffering problem. (For most commands, the output is buffered unless it goes to a terminal.) The `expect` tool can be used to circumvent these problems. Have a look at that one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something a little more complex. First redirect the output of `evolution` to a file:

```
CAMEL_DEBUG=all evolution > tmpout
```

Then make an endless `while` loop that reads the file and reacts if a string is found:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    while read line; do
    case "$line" in
        *"starting idle"*)
        echo "'$line' contains staring idle"

        WID=`xdotool search "Inbox" | head -1`
        xdotool windowactivate $WID
        xdotool key Up

        break
        ;;
        *)
        echo "'$line' does not contain starting idle."
        ;;
    esac
    done < tmpout
done
```